# Looking for most simple video codec

Tags: java, video, codec

i am looking for a simple video codec, for which it would be very easy to write a decoder in java.

it could even be a lossless codec. this is just to learn to understand how codecs work!

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [mjpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG)? It doesn't require any special hardware or acceleration, and JPEG is pretty easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Cinepak decoder is very simple, compared even to mjpeg. There are unfortunately no open source encoders but a binary encoder dll is available and usable both on Windows and on Linux via mencoder.

http://multimedia.cx/mirror/cinepak.txt

For possibly an even simpler format see

http://multimedia.cx/eggs/worlds-simplest-vector-quantizer/